# Legend at least one should be active when user clicks in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use line chart, where I am using data with line series.

For that purpose I am using the legend. When clicked the legend, the following value will be hidden, and when I click the last one it also gets hidden, in my scenario last value should not get hidden so that at least one should be active.

I have done this in pie chart series but I can't implement this in line chart why?

```
- [Js Fiddle Pie Chart Demo][1]
- [Js Fiddle Line Chart][2]
```

Comment: what's your code, and what have you tried? what did you do to make it work in a pie chart that doesn't work in a line chart?

Answer (score 1):

```
var points = this.chart.series
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qucm2km3/2/)